# JSS Quick Start issue

Tags: jss

When following the Quick Start tutorial with the commands below, I receive the attached error.

**Commands:**

```
npm install -g @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli 

jss create testtwo angular

cd testtwo

jss start
```

**Error:**

```
C:\Code\Apollo\testtwo\node_modules\@sitecore-jss\sitecore-jss-dev-tools\node_modules\del\index.js:55

module.exports = async (patterns, {force, dryRun, cwd = process.cwd(), ...options} = {}) => {

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Code\Apollo\testtwo\node_modules\@sitecore-jss\sitecore-jss-dev-tools\dist\deploy.js:7:29)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
```

**JSS** v13.0.2

**Node** v12.16.1

Comment: I think it was related to the Node version. I downgraded Node to v10.19.0 and now it seems to work correctly.

Comment: May be but i am using Node version (12.14.0)  and JSS version is (13.0.2) and it is working fine for me.